# ng-disabled fires all form validation when changes made in one form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-form

I've multiple forms in a html page where each perform some operation like add, edit.

Every form has ng-disabled directive which checks some condition and it fires it's corresponding ng-disabled function when some changes occurs.

The problem is it fires all the ng-disabled function of every form when one changes values in one form.

**Code :**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-form="myForm">
      <input type="text" required ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username">

      <button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="check() || myForm.$invalid">DO</button>
    </div>

     <div ng-form="myForm2">
      <input type="text" required ng-model="user.name2" placeholder="Username">

      <button ng-click="doSomething2()" ng-disabled="check2() || myForm2.$invalid">DO</button>
    </div>

  </body>
```

**Script code :**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.check = function() {
    console.log("check called");
  }

   $scope.check2 = function() {
    console.info("check two called");
  }

});
```

[Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcuvXLnITMHFjXNuQ2c8?p=preview)

You can see in console it runs all function when one of model changes.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Angular checks your function's value on every [digest](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) cycle to see if the button needs to be disabled

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a normal behaviour. The condition within your ng-disabled is re-executed each time your models change. So you get the 2 `console.log` each time you type something in your inputs. Then, if the return of your function is true, it disables your component, else it enables it.